# Infura - Signing transactions in a multi-user application

Tags: web3js, infura

I hope this question is not a duplicate. Since I'm using Infura as a full node, I need to send raw transactions by signing them.

In a multi-user application how would my application on the server-side sign transactions on the respective user's behalf. Saving every user's private key sounds unsafe. Would appreciate any concrete examples or sample source code on how to do this. TIA.

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/68437/metamask-and-infura-managing-and-signing-with-private-keys.

Comment: @smarx Sorry about that. I asked that question focusing on using metamask and I didn't get a usable solution. So I wanted to diverge and focus on the general solution for signing with private keys on the server and I got an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When a user registers:**

1. The user enters a memorable password
2. The client encrypts the private key with the password, and sends it to the server
3. The server receives the encrypted private key, and saves it into the database

**When a user logs-in:**

1. The server sends the encrypted private key to the client

**When a user performs a transaction available on client's web-page:**

1. The user enters the password
2. The client decrypts the private key using the password
3. The client signs the transaction with the private key
4. The client sends the signed transaction to the server
5. The server sends the signed transaction to the node

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration ! A well thought out solution.

Comment: any specific reason why client is doing the encryption and decryption, server can do it if we send the password to the server right? This way I can just send a single post request. If I do it as above I would be storing private key when logged in, signing in client which means 2 post requests one to login other after signing. Do you want to avoid sending password to the server ?

Comment: Is it ok to do everything on the server if my website is going to be on https?

Comment: @socket_var: `Do you want to avoid sending password to the server ?` - exactly. As for `https` - possibly, but I'm not a security expert, so may I suggest that you post it as a separate question on Stack Overflow (since it is not specific to Ethereum, and due to the relatively small community on this website, you're not likely to get an answer here as fast as you would on SO anyway).

Comment: @socket_var: BTW, the custom standard is that you ask the user to enter a password before **every** transaction (not just once), for security reasons. And in any case, I don't see how the current scheme yields more post requests from client to server. It is 1 for login and 1 for every transaction. How else would you reduce this?

Comment: Having a decentralized app that saves user information (keys) in a server sounds contradictory. The wallet can be kept on the client side encrypted. The question is if letting the key in memory in the browser is safe, then the password should be requested only one. This of course require that the website is open source (like myetherwallet) so that users can be assured that there is no malicious code.

Comment: Thanks @Jaime putting encryption on client side makes more sense now.

Comment: @goodvibration Yes I am actually asking the user to enter password everytime a signed transaction needs to be made, but I was just sending the password to the server and doing everything there but as Jaime pointed out I need to stick to doing the encryption on the client.

Comment: @goodvibration Scratch the 2 post requests part, I was thinking of something else. Anyway I'll try to ask these security questions on security.stackexchange.com for more dialogue. Thanks.