# How to handle password for unlock Account in web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain

In web3 there is function

`web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(address [, callback])`

to unlock the account so whenever we call the smart contract function we need to unlock the account in geth client first, so what will be the best way to store and use password on client side as I cannot prompt for password every time when it use smart contract function using web3js.

Assumption : My client side is on javascript, html and web3js

Comment: it is better to sign the transaction before sending it and not to unlock your account, but you will still have the same problem with best way to store private key

Comment: ok, so your mean I private key and use private key instead of password ?

Comment: I previously answered a somewhat similar question. You might [my answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/68452/16043) useful.