# Whats the best way to sign and send a transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumjs, private-key

Hey I want to send a transaction that has a message embedded in it. I want the most secure way to unlock the personal account. I have full node GETH installed and am using web3.I have a nodejs script running in the server that has the GETH node. I need to send transaction through this script. This script will be called by the other server. What would be the most secure way to decrypt using the private keys?
Is this a good way to unlock an account?

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(addr,pass);
```

Or is the use of private key a better one?

```
tx.sign(privateKey1)
const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')
```

I will be using to send the transaction in production server. So whats the best and most secure way to send the transaction?

Comment: The first method is not safe because anyone hacking your node server will be able to exploit your account at will. The second method safety depends on how you are storing the private key and how you are passing it to the backend server.

Comment: Hey @goodvibration. I dont think storing the private key in the GETH server is good. I have another server calling into my GETH server. I run a node script in GETH server to send the transaction. What would be the best way to save or send the private key?

Comment: Should I send this from some other server which consist of private keys? 
--->const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

Comment: As the answer below suggests, you should let your client sign the transaction. You might need to add appropriate front-end code in your project. You can read a general scheme for that, which I have suggested in an [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/68452/16043) here in the past.

Comment: There is no client code. Another JS script from another server will call my script. What would be the way to handle such communication?

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to keep your private keys off the Go Ethereum (geth) server and sign transactions locally. Namely, there are a lot of stateless Ethereum node services like Infura and QuikNode that do not support accounts.

1. Import your private key and create web3.eth.acccounts.Account object.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount

2. Then you can use `account.signTransaction()` to sign a transaction.

Comment: Whats the safest way to import the private key? I am running a script in nodejs to send a transaction in the GETH server.

Comment: The private key has to be "hot" on the server to work, so if your server is compromised the private key is with it. I would suggest you use any best practice for secrets management in development and operations. It usually comes with your deployment tool, if you use one, like Ansible has its vault.

Comment: Will this hide the private keys from anyone who has access to the server?

Comment: No, you cannot hide private keys on the server, as they need to be loaded. However, they can hide the private keys in source code control or when the files are in the rest on turned off devices.

Comment: Hey @Mikko. Would it be better just to send the RawTransaction object from another server?

Comment: No. You could still make arbitrary withdraws, it is just that another server does the same operation for you.

Comment: So is secrets management is the only option? If I have to send transactions through the server?

Comment: I think you are a bit lost how to do this and the comment section is not really good way to figure things out. I suggest you for example connect with people on web3.js chat or similar forum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108205/discussion-between-subik-and-mikko-ohtamaa).